# C++ find_if member variable of another class

Tags: c++, find, friend

So I have a class called Song, and another class Called SongLibrary.
The Songlibrary just contains a set of all songs and appropriate methods.

I am currently trying to make a function to search the song library and check if a song has a particular title.

The problem I am having is that the song title is inaccessible from the songlibrary class.

m_songs is the name of the set I am using in songlibrary to store all the songs.

m_title is the member variable for title in Song.cpp

**in SongLibrary.cpp**

```
bool SongLibrary::SearchSong(string title)
{
    bool found = false;

    std::find_if(begin(m_songs), end(m_songs),
        [&](Song const& p) 
    { 
        if (p.m_title == title) // error here (m_title is inaccessible)
        {
            found = true;
        }
    });

    return found;

}
```

I have attempted to make the method a friend of the song class but i am not exactly sure I understand how it works.

**EDIT**
I Fixed the problem using the following

```
bool SongLibrary::SearchSong(string title)
{
    if (find_if(begin(m_songs), end(m_songs),[&](Song const& p)

    {return p.getTitle() == title;}) != end(m_songs))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: Make `SongLibrary` a friend of `Song`. Or better yet, make `m_title` public.

Comment: Why does your `Song` class not have a `public` way to get the title?

Comment: because I am an idiot

Comment: That's not your only problem. The call to find_if above should not compile because the supplied predicate does not return a value.

Comment: @RichardHodges Yes bit then how do I return from the SearchSong function?

Comment: @MichaelGrinnell `find_if` returns `end(m_songs)` if nothing is found. That should be what you use determine the return value of `SearchSong`.

Comment: @RichardHodges I thought it returned a bool. Thank you so much, I got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use friend classes, you should make `SongLibrary` a friend of `Song`. But I suggest you make a public getter for your Song-title like this:

```
const std::string& getTitle() const { return m_title; }
```

Comment: Except having a public getter for only returning a member is an anti-pattern.

Comment: should be `const`, and return const reference to avoid copies.

Comment: @RickAstley: It would be debatable if return type were non-const reference, but it is not.

Comment: @Jarod42 Not really, I'll agree it's very personal but offering "encapsulation" by privating the member and then adding public get and setters is a code smell to me.

Comment: yeah I agree it should be a const ref. I updated my answer

Comment: Should all getters and setters be const ref?

Comment: @Jarod42 Agree the member function should be `const` but [I was taught](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Effective-Specific-Programs-Professional-Computing/dp/0321334876) to not return reference to internals, even a const reference. So I think returning by-value is a reasonable start and returning by reference is an optimization.

Comment: Also I believe you only need const after not before

Comment: @ChrisDrew: Returning by const ref instead of value is indeed an optimization and in rare cases, behavior can change (keeping reference of return value in member for example (as for regular variable there is life time extension)). Some libraries expose in doc return by value and explicit state that return by reference can be used instead.

Comment: @Jarod42 Sure. The classic failure case of getter returning const reference is: `const std::string& title = funcThatReturnsASongByValue().getTitle();` ... oops! But we are probably getting off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Add a "getter" function in `song`, for example

```
class Song {
    public: 
       const std::string& getTitle(){
           return Title;
       }
       ...
    private:
       ...
       std::string Title;
}
```